# How to generate runtimeconfig.json for dependency with dotnet publish

Tags: docker, .net-core, dll, devops

I'm building a .Net Core 2.1 library. It has a runnable dependency, which I need to start first.

However `dotnet publish` generates `.runtimeconfig.json` only for my library and not for my dependency.

Is there a way to force `dotnet` to generate `.runtimeconfig.json` for a dependency?

I have tried:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
    <GenerateDependencyFile>true</GenerateDependencyFile> 
  </PropertyGroup>
```

but it did not help.

As a workaround I can copy my app `.runtimeconfig.json` to the dependency `.runtimeconfig.json` but it seems hacky. Is there a better option?

I have prepared the test case, if anyone wants to take a crack at it:

```
git clone https://github.com/eduard93/gerenate-runtimeconfig.json.git
cd gerenate-runtimeconfig.json
docker build --tag mbs .
docker run --name mbs mbs
docker rm mbs --force
```

If you remove the comment from [Line 24 in the Dockerfile](https://github.com/eduard93/gerenate-runtimeconfig.json/blob/master/Dockerfile#L24) with the copy workaround the image would run successfully.

Without workaround I get this error:

```
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required to execute the application was not found in '/app/'.
Failed to run as a self-contained app. If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the /app/IRISGatewayCore21.runtimeconfig.json file specifying the appropriate framework.
```